# What is Herobrine wearing in the Rainimator series 'Fracture'?

Tags: video-games, minecraft

I am making a new animation for which I need to design Minecraft's Herobrine as a real human, so I wanted to know: **what is he wearing on his face (the grey coloured thing) in the Rainimator series "Fractures"?**

He is in the left in this image:
[image: A still from a YouTube animation; the YouTube channel name, RAINIMATOR, is in the top right hand side. Two figures are in the picture, one with a mask and glowing eyes, with a red crest on the chest (Herobrine). On the right, a character with a wither skeleton skin, and a red sword.]

Comment: What do you mean by "what does he wear"? You can see what he's wearing, it's right there in the picture. Are you asking us to actually identify each item of clothing?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that OP is asking for each item to be identified

Comment: @Valorum as each item seems to still be part of the minecraft game, this may be better suited to arqade?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - The game itself is firmly on-topic though. This falls under the heading of fanfdom

Comment: For context, [OP was redirected here from Arts & Crafts.SE](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8347/what-does-herobrine-wear-in-fractures), though they've now *also* redirected them to Arqade.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Your edit changed the meaning of the question. OP is wanting to know what the character is wearing, not what skin pack he's using.

Comment: @Valorum in minecraft they're the same thing, aren't they?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - No. A skin pack is the base exterior appearance of your character. You can add additional items and clothing as you acquire it.

Comment: @Valorum that makes sense I've not played in too long it seems

Answer (score 5):

The skin is available at [Novaskin](https://minecraft.novaskin.me/skin/1769183077/Rainimator). On close inspection he appears to be wearing a grey scarf (in-game, a *chainmail mask piece*), a black t-shirt with a thunder bird logo (in-game a *ruby chestpiece*), an *arm-guard* and a *pair of blue trousers*. He typically loads out with a diamond sword (non-enchanted) and a diamond axe.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sorry i didnt mention i just wanted to know what is on is face cause it pretends to be many things like scarf, guard, chainmail. And thanks for telling the kind of design on his armour  didnt notice that